# How to open freestockcharts.com in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

If you try to open [freestockcharts](http://www.freestockcharts.com/platform/v1) in Google Chrome it will ask you to use TC2000, Internet Explorer or Firefox because the site recquires NPAPI pluggins (which Chrome doesn't support). Is there any way to open this website with Google Chrome without having any speed/functionality drawbacks?

Comment: No. If it requires plugins, there is no way to avoid the requirement. Contact the site owner and suggest that they update their site, as even Firefox is dropping NPAPI support (and Edge never had it nor ActiveX support in the first place).

Comment: Use an alternative. There's tradingview.com, finviz.com, stockcharts.com, Google Finance and Yahoo Finance, to name some.